# EBS volume attached with boto3 has no NVMe block device

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, boto3, nvme

I need to create multiple EBS volumes and put some data there using python+boto3.

Overall my flow is:

- Create volumes.
- Wait their `available` state.
- Attach one volume.
- Wait its `attached` state.
- List NVMe devices, detect the volume's one.  <-- The issue happens here.
- Mount NVMe device.
- Copy data.
- Unmount and detach the volume.
- ... next volume.

Most of the time it works fine. Volumes are correctly attaching and linking to NVMe devices (like `/dev/nvme2p1`). But at some point linux doesn't set block device for the volume: volume state is `attached` but `nvme list` doesn't show it.

If re-attach such volume with boto3 or manually in AWS console then it will have block device.

It happens in `us-east-2` region but not in `ap-south-1`, for example.

I tried to attach/detach in single threaded and multi threaded mode.
In multi threaded mode I used separate boto3 clients per thread and a lock to attach sequentially. Also tried different boto3 versions and wait some time after attaching. Nothing helped.

My environment:

- EC2 instance: `t3a.small`, AMI: `ubuntu 20.04.2`.
- `python2` (yes, we still using it).
- `botocore==1.12.253`
- `boto3==1.9.199`

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: This seems more like a support question for Amazon than a programming question

Comment: Check `dmesg` for errors when the attachment appears to fail. Agree with @stark, this is more of a question for AWS support

Comment: Yep, probably better to ping support. I just thought someone was having similar problems. @jordanm no errors in `dmesg`.